# security to url for a user

Tags: spring, spring-security

For a url like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/update/password", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

how to be sure the connected user can modify only its password and not the one of other user...

actually, i have protection on url... but it's not enough to prevent this case

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/users/**").hasRole("USER");
```

Comment: If you share more code, you will likely get a more exact answer.

Comment: there is no code, i ask a question before doing it.

Comment: Check that the ID of the connected user is the same as the user ID in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soppuse you have a authentication over /rest/users/**. You can get **current user** with the following code.

```
YourUserPrincipalDto dto = (YourUserPrincipalDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
Long userId = dto.getUserId();
```

YourUserPrincipalDto  should implements **UserDetails**.

Comment: ok so there is no way to to this kind of check in this command: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/users/**").hasRole("USER");

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a Spring bean with a public method with username as one of the arguments (it can be in controller, security layer, service layer or DAO), you can add a `@PreAuthorize` annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("#username == authentication.name")
public void updateUserPassword(String username, String newPassword);
```

You must enable pre- and post-annotations in your security config if not already done so.

Comment: I would go that way, too but on the service layer. It really should not be on DAO.

Comment: Anyway, upvoted since at least you are using an AOP pattern instead of coding security in classes that should not deal with it.

Comment: why not on controller?

Comment: @bernardderomme if userId is the same as username, you can put it on controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) object (like [here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/b1bd8485b07dccd2c64a58e33be5ed80b52208f4/app/src/main/java/org/apache/roller/weblogger/ui/restapi/UserController.java#L248)) to your method's argument list to confirm that the authenticated user is the same user as the userId in the API URL (do whatever background DAO queries are necessary to map between the userId and the authenticated user).  Return a 403 or 404 if it is not, otherwise update the password.  Whether you return 403 or 404, best to be consistent and return the same number for both unauthorized and user-not-found situations in order to not provide unwanted information to hackers.

Comment: interesting if i could not find something with authorizeRequests... i could use this way + authorizeRequests