# How to return a custom object representation depending on the logged in user with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

The case is that I have a client-server application using Spring Data Rest on the server side and Angular on the client. In the client I want to have a profile page where users can view and modify their own data. They also can view other users profiles but without all the data, only some fields. So from the server side I want to return the corresponding representation of the user depending on whether the retrieved user is the logged one or not.

Note that some customizations will be on the associations of the User object. So that when doing a GET on `/users/id_user1/relation1` the response body must be empty even if there are some objects in this relation but the logged user is not the `id_user1`.

I think I could solve this problem implementing my own RestController but I would have to manually add the links to the object representation. So I'm asking for a better way to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have have integrated spring-security and you want to do retrieve data or what ever the problem.So you just need to know what the current user is.
These links may help you.
[security to url for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957173/security-to-url-for-a-user/37972817#37972817)

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/

Comment: I know what the current user is, the problem stays in where to place the code to differenciate between:
 - An user is retrieving his own information.
 - An user is retrieving another user information.
In order to return different fields. For example, an user can view his email but no another user email.

Comment: Since you know the current user you can exclude the other users data. You should put your logic in bussines layer and call it from controller.

Comment: I'm using Spring Data Rest so it is not needed to use controllers even it is posible to implement your own controller. I'm asking for a solution without having to use a controller.